# Can SO put "Paid Advertisement" or similar headers on blog posts that are written as extended advertisements?

Tags: feature-request, advertising, blog, stack-exchange

"Blog" posts like https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/07/25/automate-the-boring-parts-of-your-job/ are actually just extended long-form advertisements. Can this be disclosed at the beginning of the article? I realize that the by-line "Oana Chicioroaga, Community RPA Content Manager at UiPath" contains a company name, but it seems the nature of the "commercial journalism" should be more explicit.

Comment: I doubt we'll ever live to see the day SO follows ethical advertising practices

Comment: It's already tagged as partner content, but that's waaaaaaay down at the bottom. "Tags: automation, partner content, partnercontent, robotic process automation". Recently, they started adding *sponsored* below posts in the bulletin for sponsored posts, but some partner content still makes it to the bulletin without a sponsored notation, i assume because it's *technically* not sponsored content, but... i mean...

Comment: As an aside, anyone can write on the blog for free, at least after a (very bad) vetting process (that has let numerous trash articles through in the past, mostly in terms of factual inaccuracies). There's a solid chance that's "just" a guest writer rather than paid advertising, so I guess that's a loophole of sorts, but I do agree there should be some labelling clearly visible labelling when it's articles where the author writes about their own product as a general best practice

Comment: This specific example is partnered content, meaning it was written by someone that is a client of SO (presumably someone who is paying for advertising in one way or another.) I'd assume, since it doesn't include the sponsored tag, that they didn't pay to have this article presented, but surely being an advertiser gives them a leg up on getting their content posted (which *just so happens* to align with the interests of their company.)

Comment: MSE: [Can advertorial blog posts be clearly and consistently marked as such?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382097)

Answer (score 5):

It's [already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383445/200898) properly marked with "sponsored post" under the link in the right pane featuring Overflow Blog posts:
[image]

and the blog posts themselves have a fairly large "sponsored" header above the content:
[image]

Please make this change consistent across Partnered Content posts, as well.